# Searching WITHIN a single doc - Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I know that you can query a collection in Cloud Firestore to get documents that contain a certain field. However, is there a way where I can query/search WITHIN an already obtained document?

I am using it for a web app.
I know this question is a little vague and I have not provided any code, so I would be willing to provide clarification if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't provide a way to search the contents of a document snapshot that you already have.  You will have to provide code to scan its field values yourself.